# Boosting score in Elasticsearch based on aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I need to boost the score of my documents based on a particular value. That value can be obtained from aggregation query. 
Currently I am using 2 queries to do it, would like  to achieve it in a single query. 
1-So basically first query gets me the highest no of occurrence of a particular chapter based on a simple term/match query.
2- Next step is once I get the highest occurring chapter will fire another query which would basically have the same above query with another term query added with a boost factor of 10.

Any input with this regards is welcomed, if we can accomplish this in one query. Thanks in advance.

Ashit

Comment: Did you try to use a fonction score instead? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html

Comment: @LeBigCat yes have given a thought on the function score but this does not suffice my requirement. I have to determine the max occurrence of a chapter while a query is executed, I am not at all concerned with the value of chapter. so field_value_factor doesn't suffice my need here.

Comment: Did you try topHits? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html , you could retrieve your documents directly from agg result then. Maybe he should be enough in your case.